# Why the design change after Publish in .net core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I designed a website and after I published it and uploaded it to its design server it changes a bit .. (Most of it has not changed)

Some things that may be causing the problem-

1. I work with TARGET FRAMEWORK = .NET CORE 3.1
2. Part of the site is linked to a site.css file and it works fine and is also located with _layout
   And the part that is causing me problems is linked to another Layout and another CSS file

I hope you can help me it's really frustrating

Best regards

Comment: `it changes a bit` isn't a description of a problem. Most likely you forgot to include a CSS file.

Comment: I agree this is not enough information to go on.  If it is a Razor Pages or MVC app there used to be included in the template an `<environment>` tag  in the `Shared/_Layout` file that would allow you to switch which scripts and css was being loaded depending on the environment. That's just a guess though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Adam Vincent.
I had to insert the link to CSS into the

(Still it's causing me problems with the Directiorion: rtl but I believe I can fix it)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as I had tweaked some formatting in bootstrap.css. (I realize some would suggest against modifying it, as it can have unintended consequences.)  After publishing, my website looked different on the server compared to when run out of Visual Studio.  My fix (and possibly this is bad practice, I'm just not certain) was to change as follows the default code in the "_Layout.cshtml" file as follows - from:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

To:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

In summary, I simply copied from the [include="Development"] code:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

...in place of the corresponding [exclude="Development"] code:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

I hope this helps.